# Best Practice for OS Patching for Ubuntu on AWS.

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04, operating-system

I was wondering if someone can help me by sharing knowledge on Ubuntu OS patching over AWS. I tried to find it on Ubuntu documentation but my bad,I didn't get any relevant post there. Wondering if someone had already implemented process of OS patching in Ec2 machines, can share their experiences and kindly help me out here.

Regards, 
Sanjay

Comment: You mean just updating?

Comment: There is nothing special about an EC2 instance. It's just a linux server, so anything you'd do for any other linux server is equally applicable on EC2.

Comment: As far as security there actually are a few things you could keep in mind in AWS. I highlighted it in my answers. Specifically for patching, though? No.

Answer (score 4):

Just apt-get update and apt-get upgrade daily and use [AWS best practices](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-best-practices.html). Also whatever services you are running should probably be hardened to the best of your ability. There's really nothing all that fancy to it. Note major upgrades may take down services temporarily. Tweak your /etc/apt/sources.list to your liking as well.